# Класс без данных

Tags: c++, классы

Помогите понять, что собой представляет класс без данных, и где его можно/нужно использовать.

Comment: может вы имеете ввиду абстрактный класс?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, класс без членов данных может задавать интерфейс для своих производных классов. То есть такой класс может содержать лишь объявления методов (виртуальных, не виртуальных, статических).

Либо класс может быть контейнером для некоторых методов, чаще всего статических.

Comment: Сейчас появилась тенденция библиотечные статические функции располагать в классах. Например в js есть класс Math который содержит мат-методы но не содержит данных.

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите понять, что собой представляет класс без данных, и где его можно/нужно использовать.

Можно использовать в мета-программировании. Хотя для реализации парадигмы [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) принято использовать структуры.